# Jenkins BlueOcean step for deployment to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-lambda, jenkins-blueocean

I am trying to create a simple CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins BlueOcean feature. I installed the AWS lambda plugin for Jenkins & now I am able to see **'AWS Lambda deployment'** in list of step-types during step addition. But when I select this, there is a required parameter **"LambdaUploadBuildStepVariables"**. Could someone guide as to what kind of values go there ?